# Update control value when observing changes

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm observing the changes to a reactive form by subscribing to the value changes. When certain values are unset in the form, I'm setting an Angular Material Slide Toggle to false (to set the "Active" flag false for the current data record being editing).

What I'm finding is I have to defer calling setValue on the control or when it's next clicked it doesn't toggle. There is a value change event but the value is set to false still. Roughly what I'm doing is:

```
this.editForm.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
  var valid = true;
  if (!form.isRequired) 
    valid = false;
  if (!valid) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.editForm.controls['isActive'].setValue(false);
    },1);
  }
});
```

See an example without the setTimeout at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fp5tya, and one with correct behaviour and setTimeout at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fp5tya-m9yy7n. Clicking "Active", then "Required to activate" then "active" should result in both checkboxes being active. However "Active" needs to be clicked again. Similarly, clicking Active without "Required" being set will give an alert only every second click, when the form state should return to it's original state.

I consider having to use setTimeout a workaround. Is there some way to set values in the form within the observer form without deferring it?

Comment: Can you please explain what is your requirement with these two fields ? isActive and isRequired ?

Comment: IsActive cannot be set to true when isRequired is false. This means if isRequired is changed to false isActive should be set to false. Also if isActive is set to true and isRequired is false, isActive should be set back to False.

Comment: For completeness I've added a link to a stackblitz demo with correct behaviour but using the setTimeout to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely not an issue with MatSlideToggle. Firing an event immediately from within the same event's handler can be unpredictable. Whenever you need to alter the result of a change event *after* the change has occurred but before its event has completed (such as in the case of form valueChanges), the correct way to make the change is to have it fire the event after the end of the current event cycle. So using setTimeout is the correct approach here.

Comment: To clarify a bit further - Am I doing this wrong? It doesn't seem like a validator is the place to modify a control value, but perhaps it is?

Comment: I don't think so either. Validation doesn't normally _change_ values, it _flags_ invalid values (and then the form rejects submissions). However, your use case is different. I don't completely understand what you are attempting to do - it seems like "Active" is more of a status indicator than a control.

Comment: It is a status indicator, but it's also a data input. We want a user to be able to save the data entity when they are part way through entering it's details. (Some of the details may require confirmation from colleagues, and this may take quite some time). But we don't want it to be active if the details are not complete.
I've thought about it a bit more, and I think the more "angular" way to do this is to enable the save button when the form is invalid, if the "active" status is not set. Or give the user a "Yes"/"No" to deactivate if they click save when the details are incomplete.

Comment: Status indicators display status - they don't change it - so an editable slide toggle is the wrong UI for that IMO. I'm still not sure what "active" means - I think "modified" or not saved. If so, you don't absolutely need status for that, just enable the save button and manage if the user leaves the page. You could also add a "save as draft" button. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Ok then I guess strictly it is an input not a status indicaor. Active means it will be used for processing in the rest of the system. The api that the data gets saved to allows for saving an entity active or inactive. It does not allow saving an entity that is active, while other inputs are in certain states. Some of the other inputs might take several meetings with different departments to determine the corrext values for, so it is important that this information can be saved so previous input isn't lost. The api doesn't allow for saving drafts.

Comment: NB: I'm not arguing for the desired UI. I do now think using setTimeout might be the best way to achieve it if one has to.

Comment: That clears things up a bit. It sounds like two different things are going on with the active toggle - an indicator (by way of not being effectual) that the item is incomplete (not ready to be made active), and and action that actually makes the item active. Mixing the two purposes in the same toggle control makes for a confusing UX IMO, because there are actually three states, not two: not ready, ready but not active, and active. A two-state control does not effectively represent those conditions. I suspect you probably know this already but can't do anything about it.